# Background of Website wont resize on other mobile devices

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Here is this website:
http://www.morpheuscommerce.com/

Now this is what happens when i view the site on an ipad:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWyPD.jpg

A similar thing happens on iphone. On desktop it looks fine at first but when you resize the browser and move the scrollbar to the right, the background is broken is well!

Ive tried so many things to try fix this but Im not sure whats causing the problem in the first place.

Comment: I think there is some styling issue with your jQuery Slider. Try applying style to image and container: {width: 100%; margin-left: auto; margin-right:auto;}

Comment: You have fixed width on many places. You have fit that in you window. example try this #content_container, #content_width { max-width: 100%; } your first article "SAY HELLO TO MORPHEUS" will be fit in every screen. AND always use width: 100% for all images, so they will resize according to screen.

Answer (score 0):

Your website it's no responsive layout.

You can change this with css @media

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
/* Styles */
}
```

Search more about responsive layout.